# Expectation of random variable with domain $\mathbb{N} \cup \{ \infty \}$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expectation

Let us consider a random variable $X \colon \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \ \cup \{  \infty \} $. Is there a reasonable way to define the expectation value $E(X)$? How do I deal with the fact that $X$ could be equal to $\infty$? Is the expectation value always $\infty$ if $P(X=\infty)>0$?
Thanks!

Comment: Even _without_ $\infty$ as a possible value for $X$, the expectation may be infinite. Consider, for instance the probability distribution
$$
P(X=n)=\frac{6}{n^2\pi^2}
$$

Comment: thanks. that is clear to me. but how do I define the expectation value if the value $\infty$ is actually taken by $X$ ?